# MYSQL Query for Similiar/Related Products by Tags

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this 3 tables for similar/related products in my website

### Table - produtos

idproduto | produto

### Table - produtos_tags

idtag | tag

### Table - produtos_tags_id

id | idproduto | idtag

And this is mysql query

```
 SELECT produtos.idproduto, COUNT(*) AS matchedTags
 FROM produtos 
 INNER JOIN produtos_tags_id 
 ON (produtos_tags_id.idproduto = produtos.idproduto)
 INNER JOIN produtos_tags
 ON (produtos_tags.idtag = produtos_tags_id.idtag)
 WHERE produtos_tags_id.idtag IN( 
                        SELECT produtos_tags_id.idtag 
                        FROM produtos_tags_id 
                        WHERE produtos_tags_id.idproduto = '1') 
 AND produtos.idproduto != '1' 
 GROUP BY produtos_tags_id.idproduto 
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

This query is working fine is selecting the product and is matching another products with same tags.
What I want is this query to make the relationship beetween products only products it 2 or more matching tags, I try diferent things but without success.

Need some help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want products that have two or more matching tags?  To get the id:

```
select pt1.idproduto, pt2.idproduto, count(*) as NumInCommon
from produtos_tags pt1 join
     products_tags pt2
     on pt1.idtag = pt2.idtag and pt1.idproduto < pt2.idproduto
group by pt1.idproduto, pt2.idproduto
having count(*) >= 2;
```

If you want pairs with a particular product, just add the appropriate `where` clause:  `pt2.idproduto = 1`.

Comment: Yes is exacly that. This query is not working well don't see showing what I want

Comment: @Jay . . . I don't understand your comment at all.

Comment: I'm saying your query is not doing what I want... I want to show products that are related by two tags with a specific product. sorry about that